# PySpark Value Error Cannot convert column into bool

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Minimal reproducible example:

**CREATE DATAFRAME:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Start a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Create the dataframe from a list of rows
start_date = datetime.now() # Starting date
data = [(randint(1,30),randint(1,50), start_date + timedelta(days=randint(0,10))) for x in range(10)]

# Create the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("num_days", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("volume", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("period", TimestampType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
```

**ACTUAL CALCULATION:**

```
days = lambda x: x*60*60*24
windows =Window.partitionBy(unique_row_id).orderBy(F.col('period').cast('timestamp').cast('long'))

df = df.withColumn('some_calc', F.when(F.col('num_days').isNotNull(), F.collect_list('volume').over(windows.rangeBetween(-days(F.col('num_days')*7), -days(1)))))
```

**ERROR:**

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I know that the problem lies exactly in

```
(-days(THIS_PART*7)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues, firstly with how you are using [rangeBetween](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween.html). It expects two integers (start, end) as the parameters while what you are passing is of the wrong type.

also -days(F.col('num_days')*7) is not correct since you cannot directly apply a lambda function on a column, you will have to build a [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) to do so and also a udf applied to a column will still return a column type which will not fit into rangeBetween.